# weird bug? firefox - when clicking and mouseout on an icon, selection rectangle appaers

Tags: firefox, navigation, icons, href

When you click on an icon in the navigation bar and you remove your mouse from the link, a selection rectangle appaers over the whole screen. How can i prevent this. It's not reproducable with a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/woutvdd/2B3dY/ . my website: http://www.woutvdd.be.

I'm using firefox 12 and i also have this issue in ubuntu.

Someone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's Firefox behavior.

The short version of the answer is for you to apply this to your css:

```
a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: thx, this solved my problem : I just added a:focus { 
    outline: none; 
}

Comment: @woutvdd You should be aware that the outline is a visual clue to what the currently focussed element is, and people who navigate with their keyboard need this to know where they are.